# True color CImageList on Windows XP

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I have the following code in a CDialog. This code works perfectly on Windows 7, but its color is always black on Windows XP SP3.

```
UINT color_flags = CWindowDC(this).GetDeviceCaps(BITSPIXEL);

switch ( color_flags )
{
case 4 : color_flags = ILC_COLOR4; break;
case 8 : color_flags = ILC_COLOR8; break;
case 16 : color_flags = ILC_COLOR16; break;
case 24 : color_flags = ILC_COLOR24; break;
case 32 : color_flags = ILC_COLOR24; break;
default : color_flags = ILC_COLOR24;
};

CImageList imgage_list;
imgage_list.Create( 16, 16, color_flags, 0, 10 );
imgage_list.SetImageCount( number_of_bitmaps );

CDC * pDC = this->GetDC();
CDC memDC;
CRect memRect(0, 0, 16, 16);
CObject * pObj = 0;
COLORREF my_color = RGB(255,0,0);
CBitmap * bitmap = 0;
memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC); 

for ( int i = 0; i < number_of_bitmaps; ++i )
{
  bitmap = new CBitmap;
  bitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap( pDC, 16, 16 );
  pObj = memDC.SelectObject( bitmap );
  memDC.FillSolidRect( memRect, my_color );
  imgage_list.Replace( i, bitmap, 0 );
  memDC.SelectObject(pObj);
  delete bitmap;
}

memDC.DeleteDC();
this->ReleaseDC(pDC);
```

I enabled visual styles as it is suggested by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#mmc). I use this CImageList object as a parameter of [CListCtrl::SetImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y355zfta%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) member function.

Do you have any idea?

Many thanks for help.

Comment: Just looking the code looks ok, you can verify CImageList Replace member: it returns zero if it returns non ok. This i smaybe a start for debugging...

Comment: @Sunscreen: if I write out CBitmap by using CImage, the colors are correct. If I fill the CImageList from resources, the list is correct. So I am totally confused. :(

Comment: in Windows XP, are you loading common control 6 or 5.0? did u properly included manifest?

Comment: @sarat: I use common control 6. I used the manifest XML from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#mmc).

Comment: try not to delete the image list until the control is destroyed.

Comment: @neagoegab: I tried it, did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final, corrected and working code:

```
CImageList imgage_list; // class member
imgage_list.Create( 16, 16, ILC_COLOR24, number_of_bitmaps, 0 );

CDC * pDC = this->GetDC();
CDC memDC;
COLORREF my_color = RGB(255,0,0);
memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
CBitmap bitmap;

bitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap( pDC, 16*number_of_bitmaps, 16 );
CObject * pObj = memDC.SelectObject( &bitmap );

int k = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < number_of_bitmaps; ++i )
{
  // fill list control, so i is used
  // my_color is changing on every loop step

  memDC.FillSolidRect( k, 0, k+16, 16, my_color );
  k += 16;
}
memDC.SelectObject(pObj);
imgage_list.Add( &bitmap, RGB(0,0,0) );

memDC.DeleteDC();
this->ReleaseDC(pDC);
```

Many thanks for help, again.

Comment: It would be useful if you could post the corrected code in this answer, so we can see for ourselves where the problem was. Even with this explanation I'm having trouble seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized your `memDC` yet so it isn't responding properly. Before you do the `SelectObject` to select the bitmap into it, do the following:

```
memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
```

Comment: Many thanks for help. I am sorry, but I have forgotten this from the code here, but I did not forget at the real code. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

1. GdiObject * pObj instead of CObject
2. I think you need to select bitmap out of mem DC before calling Replace() like this:

   ```
   memDC.SelectObject(pObj);
   imgage_list.Replace( i, bitmap, 0 );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that in your case the bitmap is not showing up properly in Windows XP.

Though the thread talks about bitmaps not showing properly in Windows 7, which is the opposite of what you are looking for , the clue may be there .. not sure, just trying to help.

[Bitmaps dont show up properly in Windows 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/vcmfcatl/thread/4502135a-6e19-4d55-bd07-41c9970781a8).

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that my bitmap would always show up black when added to the image list.

I finally figured it out myself. Here's a stripped down version of my code.

```
// get device context
CDC* pDC = GetDC();

// create image list
imageList.Create( cx, cy, ILC_COLOR24, 1, 1 );

// Create offscreen device context
CDC memDC;
memDC.CreateCompatibleDC( pDC );

// Create new bitmap of size cx by cy
CBitmap newBmp;
newBmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap( pDC, cx, cy );

// Select new bitmap in memory for drawing
CBitmap* pOldBmp = memDC.SelectObject( &newBmp );

// do drawing here...
// e.g. memDC.FillSolidRect( 0, 0, cx, cy, RGB(255,0,0) );

/*
IMPORTANT:
Deselect new bitmap before adding to image list,
otherwise you'll potentially end up with a black icon
*/
memDC.SelectObject( pOldBmp );

// add bitmap to image list
imageList.Add( &bitmap, (CBitmap*)NULL );

// cleanup
memDC.DeleteDC();
ReleaseDC( pDC );
```

Hope it helps someone.